# Como cambiar el color de una ventana desde otra clase usando el evento de ratón (Java)

Tags: java

En el siguiente código tratamos de cambiar el color de fondo de un marco, pero no funciona. Un asunto importante es que quiero cambiar el color desde el metodo de la interfaz MouseListener y que la clase donde se encuentra sobre escrito este metodo no este anidada en otra clase

```
package graficos;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Evento_Raton {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MarcoRaton nuestromarco= new MarcoRaton();
    nuestromarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}
}
class MarcoRaton extends JFrame{
public MarcoRaton(){
setVisible(true);
setBounds(100,200,300,400);
EventosDeRaton eventoRaton=new EventosDeRaton(this);
addMouseListener(eventoRaton);

}

}


class EventosDeRaton extends JPanel  implements MouseListener{
JFrame Marco; 
public EventosDeRaton(JFrame Marco1){
Marco=Marco1;   
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("has hecho click");
    JPanel nuestropanel=new JPanel();
    nuestropanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    Marco.add(nuestropanel);

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de agregar 'nuestropanel' al frame:

```
Marco.revalidate();
```

Se llama a `revalidate()` cuando a un contenedor se le agregan o quitan componentes (con `.add()` o `.remove()`). Es una forma de decirle al Layout Manager o al AWT que la lista de componentes ha cambiado y por tanto debe 'actualizar' el árbol de componentes Swing o AWT.

Comment: Aunque esto puede responder a la pregunta, sería ideal si pudieras explicar cómo. ¿Por qué revalidar el marco solucionaría el problema?

Comment: Se llama a `revalidate()` cuando a un contenedor se le agregan o quitan componentes, `.add();` o `.remove();`, es una forma de decirle al Layout Manager o al AWT que la lista de componentes ha cambiado y por tanto debe 'actualizar' el árbol de componentes Swing o AWT.

Comment: @Johnny muchas gracias Dios te bendiga, pero sabes que tengo un programa muy parecido que en lugar de cambiar el color de un Frame cambia el color de un Panel, y el método revalidate() no funciona, este metodo funciona solo con los Frame, ¿o me equivoco?. Muchas gracias

Comment: Que tal @Julioenriquegodoymuñoz; La llamada al método funciona para cualquier elemento que extienda de JComponent; JFrame, JOptionPane, tablas, sliders, scrollbars, barras de progreso, etc.

Hay que tener en cuenta que revalidate() normalmente se hace util cuando agregas y/o eliminas componentes Swing **en tiempo de ejecución** como en este caso en un listener.

Con respecto a la otra aplicación, por favor siéntete libre y comparte el código para ver que es lo que no funciona.

Comment: @Johnny bien gracias ¿y tu?. te dejo el link a la pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79753/por-que-no-cambia-de-color-la-ventana