# ¿Por que no cambia de color la ventana?

Tags: java

En el siguiente programa se trata de que la ventana cambie de color apretando un botón, que tiene como nombre el color al que se va a cambiar la ventana. El codigo no arroja error pero no cambia el color del panel.La idea es que no tenga que anidar la clase ColorDeFondo a ninguna otra.

```
package graficos;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class PruebaEventos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MarcoBotones ventana =new MarcoBotones();
        ventana.setVisible(true);

        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
class MarcoBotones extends JFrame{
public MarcoBotones(){
setTitle("Botones y eventos");
setBounds(550,150,500,500);
LaminaBotones milamina=new LaminaBotones();
add(milamina);




}


}
 class LaminaBotones extends JPanel {

 JButton botonAzul= new JButton("azul");    
 JButton botonAmarillo=new JButton("amarillo");
 JButton botonRojo= new JButton("rojo");
  public LaminaBotones(){
    add(botonAzul);
    add(botonAmarillo);
    add(botonRojo);
    ColorFondo Amarillo=new ColorFondo(Color.YELLOW);
    ColorFondo Azul=new ColorFondo(Color.blue);
    ColorFondo Rojo=new ColorFondo(Color.red);
    botonAzul.addActionListener(Azul);
    botonAmarillo.addActionListener(Amarillo);
    botonRojo.addActionListener(Rojo);

}


}   

class ColorFondo extends JPanel  implements ActionListener{

    public ColorFondo(Color c ){

        colorDeFondo=c;

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


      setBackground(colorDeFondo);
      revalidate();
      System.out.println("apreto el boton");

    }
    private Color colorDeFondo;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ColorFondo extends JPanel  implements ActionListener{
   ...
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      setBackground(colorDeFondo);
```

Lo que dice tu código:

- `ColorFondo` es un `JPanel`. Pero nunca se agrega como componente, así que no es visible en tu ventana.
- Al ejecutarse el método, cambia el color *de la propia instancia*. Es decir, cambia el color *de un componente que no se está dibujando*.

El código parece una mezcla de dos técnicas:

- Hacer el `JPanel` implementar un listener. Pero en ese caso sería en la clase `LaminaBotones`, y se añadiría el método `actionPerformed` a dicha clase.

  En ese caso, como según que botón se haya pulsado la acción es diferente, en tu `actionPerformed` deberías consultar en el `ActionEvent` el origen del evento para saber qué hacer (qué color poner de fondo).
- Hacer que el listener tenga una referencia al objeto que quiere manipular, ya sea porque se le pasa o porque es una clase interna. Tomando de base tu código lo más sencillo es lo primero.

  ```
  class ColorFondo implements ActionListener{
     private Color colorDeFondo;
     private JPanel panel
     public ColorFondo(Color c, JPanel panel){
       this.colorDeFondo=c;
       this.panel=panel;
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        panel.setBackground(colorDeFondo);
        panel.revalidate(); // No estoy seguro de que esto sea necesario,
                            // pero hace tiempo que no toco GUI.
        System.out.println("apreto el boton");
     }
   }
  ```

  y

  ```
  ColorFondo Amarillo=new ColorFondo(Color.YELLOW, this); // Esto iría mejor en un método init que en el Constructor, leer sobre *instance leaking*. 
                                                          // Pero para este ejemplo ya va bien.
  ```

Comment: muchas gracias, Dios te bendiga, hice lo que me recomendaste y el programa funciona muy bien.

Comment: Una pequeña corrección en mi código; `ColorFondo` no debería extender `JPanel`

Comment: con y sin herencia de JPanel el código igual funciona y no arroja error. De las dos formas funciona. Lo acabo de comprobar

Comment: ahora me surge una pregunta¿por que ColorFondo sin extender o heredar de JPanel utiliza metodos de JPanel y no arroja error el codigo?

Comment: Haces `panel.setBackground()`. Llamas al método de la referencia que tienes guardada en el atributo `panel`; si hicieras solo `setBackground()` (como tenías en tu código original) ya no compilaría por que `ColorFondo` ya no tiene un método `setBackground()`.

Comment: muchas gracias estimado